# Repositories Not be Instantiated

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, repository

I'm trying to find out why I'm receiving this error. I'm following along. However the only difference is that at the time of the recording it was done with Laravel 4.25 and I am now using Laravel 5.0.

[Repositories and Inheritance](https://laracasts.com/lessons/repositories-and-inheritance)

> BindingResolutionException in Container.php line 785:
>
> Target [App\Repositories\User\UserRepository] is not instantiable.

```
<?php 
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use App\Http\Requests;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use App\Repositories\User\UserRepository;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    class UsersController extends Controller {

        private $userRepository;

        public function __construct(UserRepository $userRepository) {
            $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
        }

        /**
         * Display a listing of the resource.
         *
         * @return Response
         */
        public function index() {
            $users = $this->userRepository->getAll();

            return $users;
        }
    }

<?php

    namespace App\Repositories\User;

    use App\Repositories\EloquentRepository;

    class EloquentUserRepository extends EloquentRepository implements UserRepository 
    {
        private $model;

        function __construct(User $model) {
            $this->model = $model;
        }
    }

<?php

    namespace App\Repositories\User;

    interface UserRepository {
        public function getAll();    
    }

<?php

    namespace App\Repositories;

    abstract class EloquentRepository {

        public function getAll() {
            return $this->model->all();
        }

        public function getById() {
            return $this->model->findOrFail($id);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are type hinting an interface, and not the class itself. This error is occurring because Laravel cannot bind an interface because the binding must be instantiable. Abstract classes or interfaces are not valid unless Laravel knows the concrete (instantiable) class to substitute in for the abstract class / interface.

You will need to bind the `EloquentUserRepository` to the interface:

```
App::bind('UserRepository', 'EloquentUserRepository');
```

Comment: Is that something just with Laravel 5 because watching the video lesson Jeffrey Way doesn't add that binding to the application.

Comment: It appears as though it's in 4.2 as the docs specify it too: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/ioc#automatic-resolution . I've always specifically done the binding as it provides more clarity as to which concrete class is being used for a particular interface. Plus I often switch the class for testing. Here's the 5.0 docs about it: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/container#binding-interfaces-to-implementations

Comment: I've attempted that inside the AppServiceProvider and I'm still receiving the same issue.